# How can I randomly angle a line in java?

Tags: java, graphics

I know where I want the line to start, and I know how long I want to line to be. I want the line to start at co-ordinate 100,100 of a panel and I want it to be 50 px long. How can I randomly angle the line each run? I was thinking something like:

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int angle = rand.nextInt % 360;
```

But how do I now use this to draw the line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By passing by [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) you can easily do what you want:

```
// a random value in [0, 2PI] for the angle in radians
float angle = rand.nextFloat()*2*Math.PI; 
// length of the line
float magnitude = 50.0f;

// start point
Point2D.Float start = new Point2D.Float(100,100);
// end point
Point2D.Float end = new Point2D.Float(start.getX() + Math.cos(angle)*magnitude, start.getY() + Math.sin(angle)*magnitude);
```

Comment: That is still Cartesian, because your point is specified by an X,Y position. Polar is specified by an R,Theta.

Comment: Okay I don't totally get all of this code but after tweaking it for a few minutes I have everything working. Thanks!

Comment: @Misha: the result must be cartesian, since almost no graphical APIs support drawing directly polar points but it is calculated with polar coordinates.

Comment: @Jack You are correct that you are using Cartesian. As you mentioned it would be hard to do otherwise. Please fix the statement "By using polar coordinates". Because you ain't using polar coordinates :-)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the random angle (in radians), you can simply use Math.sin(angle)*length for height of the line, and Math.cos(angle)*length for the width. Finally you can use Grapics drawLine(100,100,width,height) to draw the line.